# split string when any numbers occur for the first time

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
$price_string = ' - £55.00';
```

Is it possible to split this string variable into two variable, at the first occurrence of any number?

For example, the above will be

```
$result[0] = ' - £';
$result[1] = '55.00';
```

Likewise, another example:

```
$price_string = ' - $1,145.99';
```

will become:

```
$result[0] = ' - $';
$result[1] = '1,145.99';
```

etc...

What I've tried so far looks like this:

```
$result = preg_split("/\D/", $price_string);
```

This doesn't seem to produce the desired result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $price_string, 2);
```

I have tested with a few numbers and it seems to be doing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use *preg_split()* then try this regexp `'~[0-9]~'` or alternatively `'~[\d]~'` and add third parameter to *preg_split()* equal to **2** (max number of elements you split into)